# Prevent client timing out while a servlet generates a large download

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a Java servlet that generates some arbitrary report file and returns it as a download to the user's browser. The file is written directly to the servlet's output stream, so if it is very large then it can successfully download in chunks. However, sometimes the resulting data is not large enough to get split into chunks, and either the client connection times out, or it runs successfully but the download doesn't appear in the browser's UI until it's 100% done.

This is what my servlet code looks like:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + report.getFileName(params) + "\"");

    try(OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
        // Send the first response ASAP to suppress client timeouts
        response.flushBuffer(); // This doesn't seem to change anything??

        // This calls some arbitrary function that writes data directly into the given stream
        generateFile(outputStream);
    }
}
```

I ran a particularly bad test where the file generation took 110,826ms. Once it got to the end, the client had downloaded a 0 byte file - I assume this is the result of a timeout. I am expecting this specific result to be somewhere between 10 and 30 KB - smaller than the servlet's buffer. When I ran a different test, it generated a lot of data quickly (up to 80MB total), so the download appeared in my browser after the first chunk was filled up.

Is there a way to force a downloaded file to appear in the browser (and prevent a timeout from occurring) before any actual data has been generated? Am I on the right track with that `flushBuffer()` call?

Comment: Is the Client a browser? Then you have very good debugging tools available to you in the client.

Comment: When I try loading the servlet URL (as a GET request) in a new tab with the Network pane of the debugger open, I can see that the request stays in the Pending state until the first chunk (of the large file) or the entire file (for the smaller jobs) is completed and downloaded. I'm not sure what else I should be looking for from the client side. It's pretty clear that the server isn't returning anything at the point where I call `flushBuffer()`.

Comment: You have to flush the buffer periodically; e.g. if you are generating data from a DB query, fetch a page, write it to the output stream and then flush it. If you expect `generateFile` to take along time, beware of DB transaction timeouts - you will have to split your work in separate transactions.

Comment: Okay. I tried a test case where I was writing a CSV file, and flushed the output stream after every line (63 lines, 24 KB total). That might help, although I'm worried about the server load of sending the response in this many chunks. Is it possible to make the browser start the download process with just the headers and 0 bytes of content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like shrinking the size of my output buffer with `response.setBufferSize(1000);` allowed my stress test file to download successfully. I still don't know why `response.flushBuffer()` didn't seem to do anything, but at least as long as I generate data quickly enough to fill that buffer size before timing out, the download will complete.